# Bootstrap 5 unused space

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

Good day

I have a question;
I am using Bootstrap 5 for my website, which works fine yet,
I want Bootstrap using the whole page and not like 80%; (See image)

[image: Main Page]

```
        <head>
            <title>Home</title>

            <link rel=stylesheet href='./style/stylesheet.css'>
            <link rel=stylesheet href='./style/bootstrap.css'>

        </head>

        <body>

            <div class='container'>

                <div class='row'>

                    <div class='col-12 navbar'>
                        <h1 class='title'>Welcome Reno</h1>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
            
        </body>
```

And my css;

```
body {
background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/M8Jq9IE.jpg);
background-size: cover;}

.title {
color: whitesmoke;}

.navbar {
background-size: cover;
background-color: gray;}
```

So how can I make it so Bootstrap uses the whole page and not have those wierd border/margins?

Thanks

Comment: instead of the class **container** use **container-fluid**

Comment: wow now i feel dumb thanks

Comment: as a side-note: You should list your `bootstrap css` first and then the `custom css`. The reason for custom-css is to overwrite bootstrap if necessary. But css is read from top to bottom so the last applied css declaration will apply (at same specificity weight).

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap's default `.container` class has a fixed width that changes depending on the breakpoint.

If you want the container to be full width at all breakpoints, you need to use `.container-fluid`.

If you want to have the full width of the container depending on the breakpoint, you need to use one of the `Responsive Container` classes like `container-sm` or `container-lg`.

In your case, it would be:

```
    <head>
        <title>Home</title>

        <link rel=stylesheet href='./style/stylesheet.css'>
        <link rel=stylesheet href='./style/bootstrap.css'>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div class='container-fluid'>

            <div class='row'>

                <div class='col-12 navbar'>
                    <h1 class='title'>Welcome Reno</h1>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
        
    </body>
```

Check out the documentation for more information:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/containers/